# Visual Studio c# project reference (using) not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference

I have 3 things in my Solution Folder, Class Library, UI 1 and UI 2. I downloaded the project with UI 1 already being done and I want to reference the Class Library (called Framework) from UI 2. Although I can see no difference from UI 1, it is working there, but not in UI 2.

From research, I noticed that the .NET version might be wrong, but all three projects are on 4.61.

```
using Framework;
```

is working in UI 1, but is giving me an error in UI 2 (The type or namespace: "Framework" couldn't be found).

Comment: Did you reference it in the project (under "References" or "Dependencies" depending on .NET Framework vs .NET Core)?

Comment: Probably as @John says your UI 2 does not reference (in its project references) the class library while UI 2 does

Comment: No. Now it's working. Thank you! (Sorry for the noob mistake, but I thought the referencing reffered to something else and not to this setting)